# make responsive menu in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

i am getting problem to modify the menu present in the wordpress. i am trying to make it responsive but i am unable to do it so please help me out.

Just visit this link to see the images and css flow of my page.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B--TMsJz_cYVYnRnRFpBOVdXYzA&authuser=0

just look into picture and look to div style which is used so please explain me how to make dropdown menu using css only to display the link......

Answer (score 0):

If you want a menu special for responsive design you could use a jquery plugin like mean menu from meanThemes.

https://github.com/meanthemes/meanMenu

Just add the css file to your theme (in header)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="meanmenu.css" media="all" />
```

add the jquery in the footer

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>
```

and initialize the menu to the container with (also in the footer)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('header nav').meanmenu();
});
```

in your document.ready